# How to long value compare?

Tags: c, stm32

BUF->src has like a 37848238928 number. 
But I want to filter with this if(BUF->src==279383903) serialprint("fine") but it cant be because BUF struct and my number is long how can I compare  with these number in if blocks?

Buffer:

```
#define BUF ((struct uip_eth_hdr *)&uip_buf[0])


struct uip_eth_hdr
{
  struct uip_eth_addr dest;
  struct uip_eth_addr src;
  uint16_t type;
};

struct uip_eth_addr
{
    uint8_t addr[6];
};
```

Comment: Propably you can use something like `if (*((long *)&(BUF->src))==279383903)`, but this is byte-order dependend code, and `BUF` should be `((struct uip_eth_hdr *)uip_buf)`

Comment: Thank you but I have this error:" cannot convert to a pointer type
 #define BUF ((struct uip_eth_hdr *)&uip_buf[0])"

Comment: From the above, `BUF->src` has a structure type, not an arithmetic type. You could compare `BUF->src.addr` to another array of 6 `uint8_t` using the `memcmp` function.

Comment: @CKocar, I have updated my comment.

Comment: 1) ethernet protocol uses big endian, while your stm32 is likely little endian, 2) `long` is probably 4 bytes on stm32, 3) many architectures allow unaligned word access. The correct way is to check individual bytes in the array.